# Finding the first letter of every element in an array

Tags: javascript

I was doing some exercises that involved using .map() and it all seemed pretty straight forward. However in one of the examples, I was tasked with using the .map() iterator to return the first letter of every item in an array.

See below the code that solved the problem.

```js
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

const secretMessage = animals.map(firstLetter => {
  return firstLetter[0]
});
console.log(secretMessage)
```

My question is, how does the firstLetter() function know to return only the first letter of each string within the animals array, rather than just returning the item at index 0 repeatedly?

Comment: Map iterates over each element and performs an action on that, the same element is never repeated. Thats why it returns the first letter of each element. Also I just noticed. firstLetter is not a function it represents an element of the array you iterate through.

Comment: `map` calls the function for every element of the array. by using an index, you get the first character.

Comment: `firstLetter` is not a function it's a string and you can access any character of string by its index just like array

Comment: try this `"abcs"[0]` in dev console you might get the idea.

Comment: `firstLetter` is actually each word of the array instead of `firstLetter` its name should have been `word`

Answer (score 1):

The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided `function` on every element in the calling array. for example:

- **Iteration 1**: `firstLetter` = `'Hen'` so `'Hen'[0]` = `'H'`.
- **Iteration 2**: `firstLetter` = `'elephant'` so `'elephant'[0]` = `'e'`.
  And so on...

Here is the documantation: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

`map()` iterates over your array, makes a copy of each value and transforms it, with each transformation result being written into a new array. On each iteration step it thinks of the current value as `firstLetter` and calls a function with it as a parameter (`firstLetter`). So `firstLetter` is sequentially `Hen`, then  `elephant` etc. On each of these you apply the function which returns the first letter of your parameter which then gets put into the new array.

The following naming should make it more clear what I mean:

```
const secretMessage = animals.map(currentValue => {
  return currentValue[0]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) accepts a function as an argument. In your case, you are passing through an anonymous arrow function. Your anonymous arrow function has an argument which it accepts called `firstLetter`. When you call `.map()`, it will execute your arrow function for every element in your array, and thus pass through this element into the function.

So, `firstLetter` doesn't really represent the `firstLetter`, but rather it represents a given element in your array. It may be clearer if you rename this argument to something more representative of what it really is:

```
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

const secretMessage = animals.map(animalType => {
  return animalType[0]; // get the first character from a given string
});
```

So, doing `animalType[0]` above will give you the first character of the given string, not the first element in your `animals` array.

Answer (score 0):

Take the 1st letter using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];


const result = animals.map(([v])=> v);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the map function iterates over every element in the array. When you access the `firstLetter[0]` you are not accessing the first element of the array `animals`, you are accessing the first character of the string `firstLetter`.

How `map` works is that it iterates over every element in a list and performs some function on it, so the code:

```
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

const secretMessage = animals.map(firstLetter => {
  return firstLetter[0]
});
```

Is equivalent to

```
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

let secretMessage = [];
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  firstLetter = animals[i] # the ith string in animals
  secretMessage.push(firstLetter[0]) # add the first letter of the string
}
```

The `map` function takes a function which takes an element as the argument, and creates an array of the return values of the function with every element in the array. So, for 'Hen', the function `firstLetter => firstLetter[0]` returns 'H', then for 'elephant' it is 'e', and so on. Then, `secretMessage` is set to `['H', 'e', ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Map iterates for each value in array.
So, assume that firstLetter at the first will point to `'Hen'` so `firstLetter[0]` is equal to `H` and so on for all others values inside array.